# Use masterpages and user controls amoung multiple .net web projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know this kind of question has been asked multiple times here but I am really looking for a solid approach to sharing masterpages and user controls across multiple web projects. The reason for this is that our current web application is just one webform project but has grown out of control. We really need to split this single web project into multiple web projects for a variety of reasons. However, when we try the various approaches mentioned on this site (ex. embedded resources, precompiliation, etc...) we always encounter warnings within visual studio and loose intellisense. We also looked into using source control as a means to share reusable controls but we would really like to avoid this sort of anti-pattern.

Overall, how can a large development team effectively split a single .net web project (webform or mvc) into multiple web projects and share reusable controls (masterpages, user controls, images, css, js, etc...) with full intellisense within Visual Studio? Any insight on this is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think you'll receive a different answer that is not already in the duplicate SO questions?  Asking for more clarity into what you are looking for.

Comment: Some of the posts in regards to this topic were a little old so I thought creating a new post might get out some new answers. I was really concerned about intellisense and I didn't see that mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jfar that your question is very broad and doesn't do a good job of explaining whey you think you answer will be different, but I'll attempt an answer anyway.

[User Controls](http://www.asp101.com/lessons/usercontrols.asp) are not designed to be shared among projects or disparate applications. They allow you to group common functionality for your specific application where the case for reuse outside of the project is small (for instance, a project drop down box allowing managers to choose different properties on a variety of pages).

If you need reusable controls that can span multiple projects easily you should be using [Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This will allow you to create, and compile, controls as .dll's that are designed to be reusable between projects.

If you really need to reuse the same controls in multiple places you should explore the pre-compiled and packed into a .dll solution offered by Server Controls. This allow the maintenance task to so solidified around the single .dll which can be version stamped and easier to track over time.

When it comes to Master Pages. You can [embed the Master Page file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shahpiyush/archive/2007/03/09/sharing-master-pages-amongst-applications-by-embedding-it-in-a-dll_2e00_.aspx) into a .dll that can be shared among multiple projects. Since ASP.NET supports [nested Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx) you should be able to embed the core Master Page while leaving it open for changes in different projects.

If this answer isn't helpful you'll have to be more explicit in what about them isn't working or makes them not worth pursuing. The clearer the question the better the answers.

Comment: Thank you for attempting to answer the question. I think this is a topic worth exploring more. Our situation is the we already developed a lot of user controls and migrating them over to server controls will be very time consuming.  I think the nested Master Page approach is interesting...will need to look into that more.